# C# insert combobox data through sqlcommand

Tags: c#, combobox

I am new to using sqlserver, I was trying to insert selected value of a combobox to the table. My code looks like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
...

con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Accounts
                                (server)
                                VALUES ('" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Data inserted.");
```

I am getting error message saying:
[image]

OCE is an item from the comboBox1 btw. It works fine when i put textBox.Text and such, but what's wrong here now? Thank you for reading! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `)` in query `VALUES()`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Accounts
                                (server)
                                VALUES ('" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')", con);
```

but i advise you to use Parameters to avoid SQL injections, like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Accounts (server) VALUES (@server)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@server", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Good spot :) +1 Mainly for pointing out SQL Injection vulnerability - one of my pet hates

Comment: @GeoffJames Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I even feel sorry that I've asked such a silly question. Thanks for your advice as well! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @JackJ Good! I'am glat to hear it :)